# "Element dl is missing a required instance of child element dd." Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, w3c-validador

Olá, estou tentando validar um projeto meu no W3C Validator.

A minha página contém uma galeria do Wordpress, aquela que você cria manualmente pelo Painel.
O problema é que, não sei porque, o W3C diz mostra esse erro

> Element dl is missing a required instance of child element dd.

A estrutura criada pela Galeria do Wordpress é essa:

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <!-- img -->
    </dt>
</dl>
```

Alguém saberia alguma forma de arrumar isso? Visto que, não tenho como editar esse código criado pelo gallery.

Se for útil, segue o link do W3C com a verificação da página.

[Link com verificação do w3c](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Foprojetoweb.com.br%2Fprovas%2Fcasarao-hotel-programado%2Fhotel-pousada-com-estacionamento-ar-condicionado-piscina-internet-e-cafe-da-manha%2F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código da galeria pode ser criado de duas formas, HTML5 ou não.

Quando o tema tem suporte a HTML5 as tags criadas são `<figure>`, `<div>` e `<figcaption>` ao invés de `<dl>`, `<dt>` e `<dd>`, usadas nos outros casos. Ambos os conjuntos representam, respectivamente: o item da galeria, o elemento de imagem, e a legenda.

Acontece que a especificação W3C da tag `dl` exige que ela tenha ambas as tags filhas `dt` e `dd`, ao passo que a especificação de `figure` não tem essa restrição, pode ter quaisquer filhos ou nenhum.

**Ou seja:** você tem duas formas de resolver isso:

1. Para que a galeria passe no validador fora do modo HTML5 você precisa inserir legendas nas imagens, que serão inseridas nas tags `dd`.
2. A outra opção é inserir esse código no seu `functions.php` para que o markup ad galeria seja alterado.

   `add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'gallery' ) );`

Comment: Cara, eu acabei descobrindo sozinho, a poucos minutos atrás, que colocar legenda resolveria. De qualquer forma, agradeço sua explicação, foi muito útil.